# Would Uber or Lyft likely have cars available on Cape Cod in the late evening

Tags: usa, uber

I'm visiting Cape Cod in this June and need to get from Logan Airport (Boston) to Wellfleet (on the Outer Cape).  I see there is a bus (the Plymouth & Brockton) but at the time I'd arrive in Logan, it would only get me to Hyannis (I'd arrive in Hyannis around 10 or 11pm).  How likely is it that Uber or Lyft would have cars available at that time?  (More generally, is there a way to find out this sort of thing short of requesting and cancelling a bunch of rides?)  I know about the fare estimator for getting the estimated fare, but I'm worried about availablility.

Comment: "is there a way to find out this sort of thing short of requesting and cancelling a bunch of rides" - no, sadly

Comment: Also, since Hyannis to Wellfleet is about 30 miles, another question is, even if there are cars available, will any of the drivers want to go that far?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with Georgio about Uber/Lyft, especially since TNC's like Uber and Lyft were still illegal in the area at the time he posted his comment. It wasn't worth saving a few dollars (only a few), and waiting forever for a ride, only to get pulled over by the PPD detective whose job it was to take these illegal service providers off the road.

Of course, times have changed. Uber and Lyft are now an option, but not necessarily a good one. The drivers are mostly tourists who don't know where they are, using GPS navigation that is notoriously inaccurate on the lower Cape. Unless you're hoping to drive directly into the Provincetown Harbor, or to get lost on overgrown, unmarked paths in the forest of Wellfleet before your driver loses the GPS signal. It's NOT worth it! And the surge prices can be astronomical!

The best bet is always to stick to the same real taxi company, and driver when possible, throughout your stay. They'll get to know you and your habits, accept responsibility for getting you home when others might turn down your fare (because they brought you there), and they may even start giving you discounts. And you'll get to where you want to be, without any need for GPS!

Somebody mentioned Cape Cab. They are OK. Town Taxi has a more limited service area. Other companies in the area that are especially good are [Black & White Taxi Cab](http://www.provincetownrides.com) and [Atlantic Rides Taxi Cab](http://www.atlanticridesptown.com).

Hope that helps. Uber/Lyft really aren't the best way to get around here!

Answer (score 2):

At that time of night, and the distance, 35 miles, availability and 'book-ability' might be an issue, as @NateEldredge correctly points out. However, both services operate in the area and [UpHail.com](https://uphail.com/) gives a fare range for Uber and Lyft of between $50-75 to go from Hyannis to Wellfleet.

As you may already be aware, taxis on the Cape can be very expensive but, if that is the only option at the time you arrive in Hyannis, [Town Taxi](http://towntaxicapecod.com/taxi-service/1958727) is reputable, as is [Cape Cab](http://www.capecabtaxi.com/). There are many choices, but these are right in Hyannis, should you find yourself there with fewer options.

My choice for that route is the ferry, taking the first leg from the Logan Terminal B (stop 2/arrivals) by bus shuttle to the World Trade Center Pier for the Fast Ferry that goes Provincetown. The airport shuttle runs every 10 minutes. The latest departure is 6:30 pm.

[Bay State Cruise Company](http://www.baystatecruisecompany.com/schedule-fares.php) runs the route three times a day, with the last departure at 5:30 pm; [Boston Harbor Cruises](http://www.bostonharborcruises.com/provincetown-ferry#faqs) runs twice a day, last departure at 6:30 pm. Both take about 1 hour 30 minutes to arrive in Provincetown.

From there, you're less than a 30-minute drive to Wellfleet. Both Lyft and Uber are more readily available in P'town, particularly in season, and would be about $25 for this ride, and a much more affordable taxi, should that be the only option by the time you arrive at the Ferry Terminal at MacMillan Pier. And Cape Cab has services from there to Wellfleet, as well.